# Babylonjs draw walking path line

Tags: webgl, babylonjs

I am trying to draw walking path lines using BabylonJS.
I tried functions `CreateLines` and `CreateDashedlines` but am unable to increase the stroke size.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8OAM3njYuM) has the path which I have in my mind Walking path:(0.20)

Answer (score 1):

Lines are usually not the right way to go if you want to control the line thickness. A line in BabylonJS always has the same radius.
You can try using One of babylon's Parametric Shapes. A tube or a ribbon take a path (in 3D coordinates) and create a 3D shape out of it. You can find the documentation along with many examples here - http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/Parametric_Shapes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CreateTube` function for draw line, with collection of path.
See this example:

http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#165IV6#68